# Facebook sharer.php does not allow my url

Tags: wordpress, facebook

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=

The above link does not allow this url.. "http://tamilagamtimes.com/"

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.google.co.in/ - its working perfectly.

But https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://tamilagamtimes.com/ - it shows 500 internal server error

Answer (score 1):

That´s because you got some serious HTML errors on your page, like missing apostrophes in href attributes, for example.

After fixing those errors, let Facebook scrape your URL again with the Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/